# Does the spell Clone require any material components to cast on a Zealot barbarian?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, barbarian

Zealot barbarians don't require any material components for spells that would bring them back to life. Would this include *clone* as well, or just the main resurrection spells that would bring you back like *revivify* and *raise dead*?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### You still need the components

The *clone* spell doesn't actually bring you back to life, but transfers your soul to an body identical to the one you cloned:

> its soul transfers to the clone, provided that the soul is free and willing to return. The clone is physically identical to the original and has the same personality, memories, and abilities, but none of the original's equipment.

The Path of the Zealot barbarians Warrior of the Gods feature only works if a spell...

> has the sole effect of restoring you to life

... which does not include *clone*.

Answer (score 13):

Clone is cast before the character dies.

### Clone spell components are still required

The description of the [*Clone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone) spell says (edited for brevity; emphasis mine):

> This spell grows **an inert duplicate of a living, Medium creature**
>   as a safeguard against death. This clone forms inside a sealed vessel
>   and grows to full size and maturity after 120 days; you can also
>   choose to have the clone be a younger version of the same creature.
>   [...]
>
> At any time after the clone matures, if the original creature dies,
>   its soul transfers to the clone, provided that the soul is free and
>   willing to return.

*Raise dead*, and similar spells, are cast after the character dies.  *Clone* still needs its components to be cast, **since the Zealot Barbarian is alive at the time of *clone's* casting**.

The [Path of the Zealot barbarian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheZealot)'s [Warrior of the Gods](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#WarrioroftheGods-645) feature says (XGtE, p. 11; emphasis mine):

> At 3rd level, your soul is marked for endless battle. If a spell, such
>   as Raise Dead, **has the sole effect of restoring you to life** (but not
>   undeath), the caster doesn’t need material Components to cast the
>   spell on you.

That is sufficient distinction for the Zealot Barbarian's class feature not to apply to *clone*'s material components.  (Clone is more complex than "has the sole effect of restoring you to life" - the clone can (and must) exist for a period of time while the player character is alive).